# Database connection issue when posting through curl

Tags: php, curl

I have a strange issue.  I'm trying to make a curl post to a page that simply connects to a database, but it is coming back as unable to connect.  If I go directly to the page in a browser, the database connects fine.  If I do the curl post through command line on my personal computer, it works, but doing the same on the actual server it fails.  I have the most up to date version of curl (7.47.1) on the server.  Any ideas what it could be?

```
Server specs:
Linux CentOS
apache 2.2.15
PHP 5.6.19
```

Using this library to make the curl requests in php:
https://github.com/rmccue/Requests

Comment: You are unlikely to get an answer without providing some code to debug. Please add your code to your question so it cab be debugged.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, figured it out.  Just in case anyone else ever runs into this, we are using a load balancer and the second server wasn't able to connect to mysql.